# How to reduse a pdf file size

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I am using `itext 7.1.17` library for creating pdf documents. I faced an issue with the rendered appearance of the non-Latin symbols. I found how to fix it, but the pdf size produced after this fix growth. Look at my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle FIELDRECT = new Rectangle(50, 750, 200, 18);
        String FIELDVALUE = "Hello";
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("FontEmbedded.pdf");
        InputStream resourceAsStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Test.pdf");
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resourceAsStream);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        String fontPath = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fonts/arial.ttf").getPath();
        FontSet fontSet = new FontSet();
        fontSet.addFont(fontPath);
        FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider(fontSet);
        PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc,true);
        PdfTextFormField ff = PdfFormField.createText(pdfDoc, FIELDRECT, "test");
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontsDir + "/arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
        ff.setFont(font);
        ff.setFontSize(12);
        ff.setValue(FIELDVALUE);
        ff.setMultiline(true);
        ff.setScroll(true);
        ff.setVisibility(4);
        acroForm.addField(ff,pdfDoc.getFirstPage());
        PdfFormXObject xObject = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, FIELDRECT.getWidth(), FIELDRECT.getHeight()));
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(xObject, pdfDoc);
        canvas.getPdfCanvas().beginMarkedContent(new PdfName("Tx"));
        canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT_PROVIDER, fontProvider);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(FIELDVALUE).setFont(font)
                                                   .setFontSize(12)
                                                   .setFontFamily("Arial");
        canvas.add(paragraph);
        canvas.getPdfCanvas().endMarkedContent();

        ff.setAppearance(PdfName.N, null, xObject.getPdfObject());

        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getFirstPage());
        pdfCanvas.setLineWidth(1f).setStrokeColor(ColorConstants.BLUE).rectangle(FIELDRECT).stroke();

        doc.close();
}
```

After running the code above I get a pdf document with size 37kb, but if I am running the code looks like the following, I get a pdf file with size 20kb.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle FIELDRECT = new Rectangle(50, 750, 200, 18);
        String FIELDVALUE = "Hello";
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("FontEmbedded.pdf");
        InputStream resourceAsStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Test.pdf");
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resourceAsStream);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc,true);
        PdfTextFormField ff = PdfFormField.createText(pdfDoc, FIELDRECT, "test");
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontsDir + "/arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
        ff.setFont(font);
        ff.setFontSize(12);
        ff.setValue(FIELDVALUE);
        ff.setMultiline(true);
        ff.setScroll(true);
        ff.setVisibility(4);
        acroForm.addField(ff,pdfDoc.getFirstPage());
        
        doc.close();
}
```

How can I reduce the size of my outcoming pdf document? If I need a solution for rendering non-Latin text in acrobat reader. The issue with non-Latin symbols is described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69044414/the-non-latin-text-is-disappearing-from-the-pdf-text-field).

Comment: does [setSmartMode()](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfWriter.html#setSmartMode(boolean)) help?

Comment: @AndréLemos yes, I did that, but it doesn't help me